# Foreign key referring to primary key in the same table Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys, primary-key

```
# Sql to create userdetails table:
CREATE TABLE `userdetails` (
 `user_details_id` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_group_id` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `email_id` varchar(50),
 `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `mobile_no` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `company_id` int(3) unsigned,
 `vehicle_id` varchar(10),
 `date_created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `date_updated` datetime NOT NULL,
 `created_by` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `status` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`user_details_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `email_id` (`email_id`),
 FOREIGN KEY (`user_group_id`) REFERENCES `usergroups` (`user_group_id`),
 FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `companies` (`company_id`),
 FOREIGN KEY (`created_by`) REFERENCES `userdetails` (`user_details_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Focusing on the 'user_details_id' and 'created_by' columns, the conflict arises when created_by is not referring to an existing user_details_id.

Meaning, if I am creating my own profile with the required details, my user_details_id has not been generated yet and hence I do not know what value to input into the created_by field (which is ideally supposed to contain my user_details_id).

I would appreciate if anyone can guide me in the right direction on how to approach such a conflict, and if there is a way to determine what the value of the user_details_id field could be before it's even generated.

Thanks.

Comment: Allow null for `created_by`

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid just to clarify, I want the created_by field to be not null, and as a result to hold the value which would be the corresponding user_details_id.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I ended up allowing null for created_by, since that seems like the simplest solution to my approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Sql to create userdetails table:
CREATE TABLE `userdetails` (
 `user_details_id` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_group_id` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `email_id` varchar(50),
 `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `mobile_no` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `company_id` int(3) unsigned,
 `vehicle_id` varchar(10),
 `date_created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `date_updated` datetime NOT NULL,
 `created_by` int(3) unsigned,
 `status` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`user_details_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `email_id` (`email_id`),
 FOREIGN KEY (`user_group_id`) REFERENCES `usergroups` (`user_group_id`),
 FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `companies` (`company_id`),
 FOREIGN KEY (`created_by`) REFERENCES `userdetails` (`user_details_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Allowing created_by to accept NULL values seems to be a quick fix to this problem as that can imply user is self-created.

Answer (score 0):

You can't handle it by temporarily disabling foreign key checks by setting server variable `foreign_key_checks`

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

INSERT INTO cities userdetails(....);

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Comment: Just to clarify, I want the created_by field to be not null, and as a result to hold the value which would be the corresponding user_details_id. Is that possible?

Comment: yes, you will be able to postpone check constraint operation